# Independent web components using single stenciljs project

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, web-component, stenciljs

Is it possible to setup a single StencilJS project that can have multiple web components independent of each other?

As of now I can see there are 2 seed projects that can be used for developing component and app respectively.

I have a use case where we want to manage all our components at single place. We want to generate/build independent component scripts but don't want to have multiple package.json and build process for each component.

Comment: Hi Rahul, Did you find any solution for this? I'm also looking to havesingle repo, but want to ship independent compiled components.

Comment: @ShivajiVarma   in latest version of StencilJS, there is an option for this:
https://stenciljs.com/docs/custom-elements. It won't generate multiple npm modules, but have separate bundles for components, so that your consumers can register only what they want to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Latest version of StencilJS supports component specific bundles:
[Custom Elements Bundle](https://stenciljs.com/docs/custom-elements).
You can configure `stencil.config.ts` to generate this kind of bundles along with combined bundles.

**Please Note**:

> you will still be shipping all components into a single npm module,
> but your consumers will now have a choice to register only components
> of their interest.
>
> If you wish to have separate node modules using single source code
> repo, you should setup a monorepo using [Lerna](https://lerna.js.org/) or [yarn 2
> workspaces](https://yarnpkg.com/features/workspaces)

Answer (score 2):

The common practice is to have a single repo with many sub directories that each have a component. Each component has it's full build process and `package.json` but [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna) is used to run one command to build/test/publish all of them at once.

Comment: I don't think Lerna is the specific tool Stencil uses, but otherwise you're correct.Both projects (stencil-component-starter and stencil-app-starter) have a `src/components` you can add multiple components into.